# Burnside's Lemma to count the number of ways to write an integer as a product of three positive integers

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am asked to find the number of distinct ways to express 1,000 as a product of three integers using Burnside's Lemma. By distinct ways, I mean that the order of the factors is not important, e.g., $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 125$ is not distinct from $125 \cdot 4 \cdot 2$. I am aware that there are several similar questions to this, but none that I see use Burnside's Lemma:

$$|X / G| = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} |X^{g}|.$$

Here $|X / G|$ is the number of $G$ orbits and $X^{a}$ is the number of points fixed by a permutation $a$ in $G$.

I understand the lemma and its proof, but I am not sure what group and group action is relevant to the number 1,000 for this problem. I'm fairly certain that I have to consider the prime factorization: $2^{3}5^{3}$.

Any help on making sense of this question is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can take $G=S_3$ and $X$ to be the set of all triples of positive integers whose product is $1000$. $G$ acts naturally on $X$, by permuting the coordinates. Then you indeed look for the number of orbits of this action. This doesn't look like a very good way to compute this number, though.

Comment: @Mark I get what you are saying. At least finding the cardinality of $X$ isn't too terribly hard. You see that $1000 = (2^{a}5^{r})(2^{b}5^{s})(2^{c}5^{t})$ where $a + b + c = r + s + t = 3$. Where these variables are integers from $\{0,1,2,3\}$. If I am not mistaken, $|X| = 100$. The task of finding the orbits remains, but it seems a lot less daunting now, so thank you.

Comment: @Sil Yes, it appears this does answer my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been able to come to an answer with the help of one of the comments. We consider the set $X$ to be the set of all (not necessarily unique) products of $3$ integers that equal $1000$. We express these products as $3$-tuples. The group $S_{3}$ acts on this set by permuting the elements in each $3$-tuple.

We first observe that the cardinality of $X$ is $100$ after considering the method from my comment to my own post. We see that the identity of $S_{3}$ fixes all $100$ elements of $X$. We see that each of the three transpositions individually fix four elements of $X$ giving us $12$ more fixed points. We then observe that the two $3$-cycles only fix the tuple $(10,10,10)$ giving us two more fixed points.

$$
\dfrac{100 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 1 + 1}{3!} = 19
$$

This number is the same as my "brute force" calculation, so I am reasonably confident in my answer.